# flutter_svg loads minified version in web build

Tags: flutter, svg

I use `flutter_svg` to display SVG files. It works **fine in DEBUG mode** on the computer but the **build version is broken** and tries to load the SVG file from another path: `minified:fi.svg`.

When I use the debug version, it uses this URL successfully:
localhost:39469/assets/assets/img/chakra-map/**nochakra.svg**

The version built and deployed to GitHub Pages is using another URL though:
assets/img/chakra-map/**minified:fi.svg**

```
Uncaught : Unable to load asset: "assets/img/chakra-map/minified:fi.svg".
    c js_helper.dart:1196
    $1 asset_bundle.dart:324
    zJ zone.dart:1661
    $0 future_impl.dart:127
    q_ future_impl.dart:867
    lj future_impl.dart:643
    $0 future_impl.dart:713
    aAf schedule_microtask.dart:40
    aAz schedule_microtask.dart:49
    $1 async_patch.dart:48
```

You can browse the files [in this commit](https://github.com/niccokunzmann/open_chakra_toning/tree/1448a858f51b1fe0bb2b1d316ecd75cce6ed136c)
And actually, I deploy the app to [GitHub pages](https://niccokunzmann.github.io/open_chakra_toning/).

How can I correct my code so that the normal and not the minified SVG version is loaded? Is this a bug that should be reported?

---

Search

```
grep -r 'minified'
main.dart.js:return"minified:"+a},
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62259): You cannot rely on the **class name** because the minification removes it.

That is why `minified:` was part of the SVG. Not the SVG is minified but the path of the SVG is built using the class name.